# Make port appear as subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, port, subdomain, mod-proxy

I have Jira set up to serve on `myserver:8080`.

There is an DNS A reference that points `jira.otherserver` to the ip address of `myserver`.   (`otherserver` is going to host the Jira setup in the future)

Based on other answers here, I tried enabling mod_proxy, and added the following to my `httpd.conf` on `myserver`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jira.otherserver/
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass http://jira.otherserver/ http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse http://jira.otherserver/ http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I visit `http://jira.otherserver` it gives me the generic start page (phpinfo).  I can still access jira at `http://myserver:8080`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I can also access Jira at `jira.otherserver:8080`, so DNS is working correctly

Edit 2: I followed the suggestions in an answer, and modified the section to

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jira.software-task
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8080/"

    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8080/"

</VirtualHost>
```

Now connecting to `jira.otherserver` causes an error 500, with the following in the logs:

> ```
> [Fri Nov 18 13:40:03 2016] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
> ```

`httpd -M` outputs the following:

> ```
> M:\>httpd -M
> Loaded Modules:
>  core_module (static)
>  win32_module (static)
>  mpm_winnt_module (static)
>  http_module (static)
>  so_module (static)
>  actions_module (shared)
>  alias_module (shared)
>  asis_module (shared)
>  auth_basic_module (shared)
>  authn_alias_module (shared)
>  authn_default_module (shared)
>  authn_file_module (shared)
>  authnz_ldap_module (shared)
>  authz_default_module (shared)
>  authz_groupfile_module (shared)
>  authz_host_module (shared)
>  authz_user_module (shared)
>  autoindex_module (shared)
>  cgi_module (shared)
>  dav_module (shared)
>  dav_fs_module (shared)
>  dir_module (shared)
>  env_module (shared)
>  include_module (shared)
>  isapi_module (shared)
>  ldap_module (shared)
>  log_config_module (shared)
>  mime_module (shared)
>  negotiation_module (shared)
>  proxy_module (shared)
>  rewrite_module (shared)
>  setenvif_module (shared)
>  dav_svn_module (shared)
>  authz_svn_module (shared)
>  php5_module (shared)
> Syntax OK
> ```

Comment: That configuration makes your webserver an open proxy that can be abused by anyone to proxy to any web site anywhere. That is what `<Proxy>` is for, and should never be present in a reverse proxy setup (or, generally, at all).

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's only visible from the internal network, but I will improve it.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable Virtual Hosts on port 80: `NameVirtualHost *:80` before `<VirtualHost *:80>` and remove trailing slash from `ServerName jira.otherserver/`

Comment: I made those changes, and no change in result.

Comment: And now lets fix `ProxyPass` directive: `ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8080/"` and `ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8080/"`

Comment: That causes an error 500.  Logs show "[warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule."

Comment: Add `LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache22/mod_proxy_http.so` or some other path instead of `libexec/apache22` you use for loading proxy_module

Comment: It's currently `LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so`

Comment: I enabled `mod_proxy_http`, and it works now.

Comment: So try adding `LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so` and restart Apache

Comment: And I can now copy and paste for the other services.  Thank you hugely.